# Handling categorical variables for Xgboost?

Tags: scikit-learn, xgboost, feature-engineering, encoding

Currently there seems to be two approaches for handling categorical variables in gbdts:

- Xgboost as an option, but data need to be encoded properly (integers)
- Catboost can handle everything provided you specify the columns

I tried both, and Catboost has a performance that is significantly above. I can't exclude the difference in perfromance is due to some performance in the algo. However I am wondering if it could be due to that encoding as it is the only difference I use in pipeline. Code is provided below:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import OrdinalEncoder

cat_features = train.dtypes[X.dtypes=='object'].index.values.tolist()
enc = OrdinalEncoder(handle_unknown='use_encoded_value',unknown_value=-2)

train[cat_features] = enc.fit_transform(train[cat_features])
test[cat_features] = enc.transform(test[cat_features])
```

Can someone pinpoint if there is something inherently wrong with this approach, that would prevent Xgboost to perform as well as catboost ?

Comment: May I ask why specifically did you choose `OrdinalEncoder` as the encoder?

Comment: Xgboost now seems to be able to handle categorical as long as they are encoded as an array of different integers. Ordinal encoders enforce this.

Comment: Could you include the model definitions and fitting code? (A sample dataset would be great too, if you can manage it.)

Answer (score 1):

<s>My first thought is that xgboost is interpreting the OrdinalEncoder as any other numeric variable rather than distinct, unordered categories. If you have a true categorical variable (where each category is exchangeable with another), then it is incorrect to use the OrdinalEncoder because this will assign a **ranking** to each category.</s>

For example: if I have a categorical variable with categories red, blue, and orange, running OrdinalEncoder on this feature will replace this with values 1, 2, and 3, respectively. Say missing categories are assigned -2 like in your example. In this case, notice that this implies in some sense that orange is closer to blue than it is to red, red is closer to "orange" then it is to missing, and so on! This is likely not what you intend.

The result is that xgboost will view this as a numerical variable where the following splits can be made within a particular decision tree with this feature:

- $\leq 1$ = category 1 and missing vs. 3
- $\leq 2$ = category 1, 2 and missing vs. 3

Notice that I can't group categories 1 and 3 together as a possible split as well when treating the feature as an Ordinal variable. If you **switch the encoding method to OneHotEncoding** instead, the performance of xgboost should improve. I'd also read [this](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorials/categorical.html) page of documentation, which describes the (limited) native handling of categorical variables within xgboost 1.6.

EDIT: Upon further clarification from OP in the comments, the above text is not likely the culprit (assuming that in their pandas dataframe, a categorical variable is declared as the type of the column and enable_categorical = True in the call to the xgboost  fit function). I am still convinced, however, that running the catboost encoder on the categorical variables and then fitting as per usual will give results similar to running catboost natively, as per below.

catboost handles categorical variables in a much more clever way - instead, it [numerically encodes the categorical variables in a supervised fashion](https://catboost.ai/en/docs/concepts/algorithm-main-stages_cat-to-numberic). Instead of OneHotEncoding with xgboost, you could switch to using the [CatBoost encoder from the category_encoders package](https://contrib.scikit-learn.org/category_encoders/catboost.html) as a drop in replacement and likely get similar results to catboost.

Comment: I am talking about xboost support for categorical (see: https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorials/categorical.html). It's not just treating categorical as numeric. However I am tempted to accept your answer as the Catboost encoder would answer my question.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment, I would say just **restricting yourself to one encoder** might not be a wise choice. There are a lot of different types of encoders out there and each will give you a different level of accuracy/performance. Also `XGBoost` and `CatBoost` can be used with **any kind of encoder not just `OrdinalEncoder`.**

The reason you are getting different result with both the above mentioned models (`CatBoost` and `XGBoost`), is not only because the **model architecture is different**, but also because the **encoding techniques are different** in both the models. Both the models are handling the categorical variables differently.

I would suggest that you **try different encoding algorithms on both the models** and then select your final model. This is the usual way to go when selecting the final model. You try different things and then based on the results, you select the final model. [Here](https://contrib.scikit-learn.org/category_encoders/) is a list of different encoders you can implement in python. Try all these encoders and then select the final model.

**Cheers!**